# Operations on sets with answers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let U = {x:x∈Z⁺, 0<=x<=10}, A= {x:x∈Z⁺ and x²<=10}, B= {x:x∈U and x is prime number}, C= {x:x²-4x+4=1}. Find

(i)A ∩ B
(ii)C-A
(iii)A-(B⊕c̅ )

Is it the answer for (i) is {1,2,3}, (II) is {} and (III) is {2}?
thanks.

solution
A={0,1,2,3}
B={1,2,3,5,7}
C={1,3}
c̅ ={0,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}

i.A ∩ B={1,2,3}
ii.C-A={}
iii.A-(B⊕c̅ )= {2}

Comment: Show (in the question) how you get to these answers so that your way of working can be checked and your mistakes can be marked.

Comment: what is $\overline {c}$? and what is the meaning of $B \oplus \bar{c}$?

Comment: @drhab edited ^^

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ denotes the positive integers so $U=\left\{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\right\} $
and $A=\left\{ 1,2,3\right\} $. Then $B=\left\{ 2,3,5,7\right\} $
($1$ is not a prime number). I have the same questions as @Krish.